# How to trick the SYS_read execution with ptrace

Tags: linux, system, system-calls, ptrace

I'm wondering whether we could use **ptrace** to trick a syscall execution. For example, can we trick the `SYS_read` with a pre-defined input, so that application users will not have to type anything from the keyboard? Thanks!

Comment: This looks like a good article on it: https://nullprogram.com/blog/2018/06/23/

Comment: @AndrewSun There is a problem with the method above. The `SYS_read` is always blocked to wait for any user input. My question is how can we "feed" the user input with ptrace (or other methods), and let `SYS_read` continue execution.

Comment: Could you not just copy the data into the buffer yourself and cancel the original syscall using the technique described in the article?

Comment: By the way, is there a reason you couldn't just use pipes to redirect stdin?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I feed the read input buffer with `ptrace(PTRACE_POKEDATA, ...)` and replace the `SYS_read` with `SYS_getpid` to get things to work. It's just a research project that has to manipulate syscalls.